# Where to place the IIS module dll file?

Tags: asp.net, iis, httpmodule

I have created an IIS module with a class implementing `IHttpModule`. In my localhost, I just copy its dll to the `bin` folder of the testing web app project, and then add the module in `web.config`.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="AppendOutput" />
  <add name="AppendOutput" type="AppendOutput.AppendOutputModule" />
</modules>
```

Now I need to deploy the dll to my IIS server, where other web apps can use the module also. What is the shared or common folder to place that dll? And how should I revise the add module line to point to the correct path?

```
  <add name="AppendOutput" type="AppendOutput.AppendOutputModule" />
```

I was reading [Walkthrough: Creating and Registering a Custom HTTP Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx), but it appears it does not tell us how to deal with the dll deployment.

Another tech net article on [Add a Managed Module (IIS 7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754939) tells about how to add Managed Module. But the there is nothing in my **Type** drop down list.

[image: add managed module]

Comment: I've added .dll to bin folder and I am able to see my module in Type dropdown. But I also looking for more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a Native Module with the path of your dll
(Available at Modules over IIS home, not Sites)

[image]